# React native Firebase iOS Production not working by sending noti to FCM single device

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications

I'm doing a React native project with notification, using APNs Authentication Key
. It works perfectly fine on **android** and **iOS dev**.

But when I export ipa as **adHoc** run on device, the app stop receiving notification when I send noti to a **single device using FCM**. It only works if I send to all **iOS devices**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send notification via postman for sent specific user. I think this issue will be the wrong user_key.

POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

headers:
Authorization:Key='YOUR_SERVER_KEY'
Content-Type: application/json

BODY: raw Data

```
{
  "to": "User_key",
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "title": "Hello world",
    "body": "Hello...",
    "image": "https://vortex.accuweather.com/adc2010/images/icons-numbered/01-l.png",
    
    "media_type": "image",
    "message": "message message message messagemessage message",
    "attachment": "https://vortex.accuweather.com/adc2010/images/icons-numbered/01-l.png"
  },
  "notification": {
    "android_channel_id": "news",
    "sound": "default",
    "title": "Hello world",
    "body": "Hello...",
    "image": "https://vortex.accuweather.com/adc2010/images/icons-numbered/01-l.png"
  }
}
```